# Javascript: Run a script depending on which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, function, button

Can someone enlighten me on this please. I was trying to implement a simple Javascript function. The idea is, to run a conditional script depending on which button is clicked. Can't seem to figure this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function whichButton(){

if(//Button 1 is clicked...){
    //Run script 1   
 }
else if(//Button 2 is clicked){
    //Run script 2  
 }
else if(//Button 3 is clicked){
    //Run  script 3  
 }
else if(//Button 4 is clicked){
    //Run script 4  
 }
else{
    //Do nothing
 }
}
</script>

<form id="form1" onSubmit="whichButton();">
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button><br/>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button><br/>
<button id="btn3">Button 3</button><br/>
<button id="btn4">Button 4</button><br/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does "run script" mean? do you mean "to download a new script file and run it" or just "to run different functions"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add onclick handlers to the button tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function whichButton(buttonElement){
  alert(buttonElement.id);
  var buttonClickedId = buttonElement.id;
  if( buttonClickedId === 'btn1' ){
     // do btn1 stuff
  }
  else if( buttonClickedId === 'btn2' ){
     // do btn2 stuff
  }
  // ...
  else{
     // don't know which button was clicked
  }

}
</script>

<form id="form1" >
<button id="btn1" onclick="whichButton(this)">Button 1</button><br/>
<button id="btn2" onclick="whichButton(this)">Button 2</button><br/>
<button id="btn3" onclick="whichButton(this)">Button 3</button><br/>
<button id="btn4" onclick="whichButton(this)">Button 4</button><br/>
</form>
```

EDIT:

To run different code based on which button was clicked, use an IF statement similar to your original post, which I've edited above.  // you can take that alert out, or move into each if/else if scope.

Comment: This one seems to work THANKS!, but how can I run a different block of code for each specific button? Like run code 1 if btn1 is clicked, run  code 2 if btn2 is clicked, and so on....? Where do I go about placing the conditional statement?

Comment: @user1881287 -- See my edit comments and the function body of whichButton, where I've added back your if/else if statements, changed slightly to match on the buttons' `id` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the from to your function, then find the active element:

```
<form id="form1" onSubmit="whichButton(this);">
    Buttons...
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function whichButton(form) {
    var clicked = form.querySelector(":active");
    switch(clicked.id) {
    case "btn1":
        // do stuff
        break;
    // add more cases
    }
}
```

Note that I'm not certain about this, but I've tested it and it seems to work. Note that IE7 and older do not support `:active`, I have no idea how to make this work in those older versions.

EDIT: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuQgU/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: @netizen0911 yes it does

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jQuery the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", "button.btn", function(){
                console.log("You clicked " + $(this).html());
                return false;
        });
</script>
<form>
<button class="btn">Button 1</button><br/>
<button class="btn">Button 2</button><br/>
<button class="btn">Button 3</button><br/>
<button class="btn">Button 4</button><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: @kolink  -- why jquery bad?

Comment: Well for starters the OP's not using it. Second it's completely unnecessary here. Third it doesn't answer the question in a valid way, since it doesn't use the `onSubmit` event anymore.

Comment: and adding onclick foreach button is better and more efficient?

Answer (score -1):

Use AJAX to get the scripts, insert them somewhere in the DOM and use initialize() to run them.

```
$.get('js/script1.js', function(data) {
    $('#dummydiv').html(data);
    initialize();
});
```

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Oh. I misinterpreted 'conditional' script as 'dynamic' or whatever.

Comment: Okay, that's fair enough, but what's with the jQuery? There is no jQuery here.

Comment: Well, the written solution can still be applied to vanilla JS.

Comment: So why not give it in vanilla JS? Why the jQuery?

Comment: At the cost of a 32Kb file! Do you have any idea what you can DO in 32Kb of vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Let's be realistic. Most people would have jQuery cached from Google anyway.

Comment: Well, fine. If you want to sit around waiting up to 10 seconds for a simple page to load because the creator thought it would be cool to use jQuery for everything, be my guest. Meanwhile I'll be here with a page that happily reports `This page was generated in 0.013, downloaded in 0.316 and rendered in 0.362 seconds`